# Simplified method with multiple if-else

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-2+

I need to refactor some pice od method for drag-and-drop angular material.

Here is a working method in production, I need suggestion for CLEAN way to write this method.
I can't change var name and anything...

**WHAT I TRY** - I try to made small functions for every if/else, but in this case, I missing this drop event.
Like this example

```
checkIfHasRole() {
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
    let lastAddedRole = event.container.data[event.previousIndex];
    if (lastAddedRole !== undefined) {
      this.userRoleCopy.push(lastAddedRole.valueOf());
    }
```

But, in this case, all `event` is missing

Here is the working method in production

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop < string[] > ) {
  if (event.container.id === "delete") {
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
    this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
  } else {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      let lastRole = Object.values(
        event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]
      );
      let parentRole = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.container.data));

      let hasRole = parentRole.some(rola => {
        return rola.role === String(lastRole);
      });

      if (!hasRole) {
        transferArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data,
          event.container.data,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );
        let lastAddedRole = event.container.data[event.previousIndex];
        if (lastAddedRole !== undefined) {
          this.userRoleCopy.push(lastAddedRole.valueOf());
        }
        this.resetList();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, this could use a refactoring

I think your instincts are correct.  Those nested `if-else`s are hard to comprehend.  And the simplest way to break it apart is by creating helper functions.

Here I go through a step-by-step refactoring.  As with any refactoring, it involves a number of judgment calls.

### Assumptions

First, I need to make clear one assumption, as not everything was spelled out in the question.  I'm assuming that the `data` properties of the `event`'s `container` and `previousContainer` nodes, as well as your `this` object's `userRole` and `userRoleCopy` nodes consist of arrays of objects of the form `{role: 'some string'}`.

### InitialCode

We start with code that looks like this:

> ```js
>   drop: function(event)  {
>     if (event.container.id === "delete") {
>       transferArrayItem(
>         event.previousContainer.data,
>         event.container.data,
>         event.previousIndex,
>         event.currentIndex
>       );
>       this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
>     } else {
>       if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
>         moveItemInArray(
>           event.container.data,
>           event.previousIndex,
>           event.currentIndex
>         );
>       } else {
>         let lastRole = Object.values(
>           event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]
>         );
>
>         let parentRole = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.container.data));
>
>         let hasRole = parentRole.some(rola => {
>           return rola.role === String(lastRole);
>         });
>
>         if (!hasRole) {
>           transferArrayItem(
>             event.previousContainer.data,
>             event.container.data,
>             event.previousIndex,
>             event.currentIndex
>           );
>           let lastAddedRole = event.container.data[event.previousIndex];
>           if (lastAddedRole !== undefined) {
>             this.userRoleCopy.push(lastAddedRole.valueOf());
>           }
>           this.resetList();
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
> ```

This code implies that there two helper functions available: `transferArrayItem` and `moveItemInArray`, and also that the `this` object also has the method `resetList` and the properties `userRole` and `userRoleCopy`.  I created dummies for these, with a wrapper I creatively (:-)) called "something".  You can see it in [Step 0](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%28event%29%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.container.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20event.container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastRole%20%3D%20Object.values%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20parentRole%20%3D%20JSON.parse%28JSON.stringify%28event.container.data%29%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasRole%20%3D%20parentRole.some%28rola%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20rola.role%20%3D%3D%3D%20String%28lastRole%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21hasRole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastAddedRole%20%3D%20event.container.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28lastAddedRole%20%21%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28lastAddedRole.valueOf%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A).  I of course do not expect that these helper functions do anything like your original.  The goal here is to simply fix things up without changing the behavior.

### Removing unnecessary clone

My first step was to remove an unnecessary clone made in this:

> ```js
>         let parentRole = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.container.data));
>
>         let hasRole = parentRole.some(rola => {
>           return rola.role === String(lastRole);
>         });
> ```

There is no advantage to cloning that parent role.  The call to `some` does not alter the data, so we can just use the original.

Thus we can just write:

```js
        let hasRole = event.container.data.some(rola => {
          return rola.role === String(lastRole);
        });
```

This minor change is available in [Step 1](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%28event%29%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.container.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20event.container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastRole%20%3D%20Object.values%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20parentRole%20%3D%20JSON.parse%28JSON.stringify%28event.container.data%29%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasRole%20%3D%20parentRole.some%28rola%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20rola.role%20%3D%3D%3D%20String%28lastRole%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21hasRole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastAddedRole%20%3D%20event.container.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28lastAddedRole%20%21%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28lastAddedRole.valueOf%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A), and you can see just by switching tabs that the output remains the same.

### Tweaking the search

This code seems odd:

> ```js
>         let lastRole = Object.values(
>           event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]
>         );
>
>         let hasRole = event.container.data.some(rola => {
>           return rola.role === String(lastRole);
>         });
> ```

Perhaps my initial assumption was wrong.  But if you're trying to see if that data object has an element whose `role` property matches the specified value, I believe it's much simpler.  This is available in [Step 2](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%28event%29%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.container.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20event.container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastRole%20%3D%20event.previousContainer.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D.role%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasRole%20%3D%20event.container.data.some%28rola%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20rola.role%20%3D%3D%3D%20lastRole%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21hasRole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.container.data%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastAddedRole%20%3D%20event.container.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28lastAddedRole%20%21%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28lastAddedRole.valueOf%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A).

```js
        let lastRole = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].role

        let hasRole = event.container.data.some(rola => {
          return rola.role === lastRole;
        });
```

### Stop repeating `event.x.y`

Repeating `event.something.somethingElse` all over the place makes the code both harder to read and harder to change.  We can capture values like `prevData` and `id` from the event, and the rest of the code will be simpler.  There are several ways we could do this, but I find the nicest one is with [destructuring parameters](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#parameter-handling).  Using that, we can simplify the code to version [Step 3](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20event%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20container%2C%20container%3A%20%7Bid%2C%20data%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20previousContainer%2C%20previousContainer%3A%20%7Bdata%3A%20prevData%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20currentIndex%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20event%0A%20%29%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastRole%20%3D%20prevData%5BpreviousIndex%5D.role%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasRole%20%3D%20data.some%28rola%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20rola.role%20%3D%3D%3D%20lastRole%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21hasRole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastAddedRole%20%3D%20data%5BpreviousIndex%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28lastAddedRole%20%21%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28lastAddedRole.valueOf%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A):

```js
  drop: function ({
    container, container: {id, data},
    previousContainer, previousContainer: {data: prevData},
    previousIndex,
    currentIndex
  }) {
    if (id === "delete") {
      transferArrayItem(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
      this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
    } else {
      if (previousContainer === container) {
        moveItemInArray(data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
      } else {
        let hasRole = pluck('role', data).includes(prevData[previousIndex].role)

        if (!hasRole) {
          transferArrayItem(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
          let lastAddedRole = data[previousIndex];
          if (lastAddedRole !== undefined) {
            this.userRoleCopy.push({...lastAddedRole});
          }
          this.resetList();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### Using helper functions

I'm still bothered by this bit:

> ```js
>         let lastRole = prevData[previousIndex].role
>
>         let hasRole = data.some(rola => {
>           return rola.role === lastRole;
>         });
> ```

If we were working with `['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3', ...]`, it would be very easy to search for our target role by just calling `includes`.  I happen to have handy a helper function that transforms `[{x: 'a', y: 1}, {x: 'b', y: 2}, {x: 'c', y: 3}...]` into `['a', 'b', 'c']`, a function called `pluck`.  In fact it's built into the [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) REPL I've been using, but we could write our own as easily as this:

```js
const pluck = (prop) => (xs) => xs.map(x => x[prop])
```

and use it as in [Step 4](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20container%2C%20container%3A%20%7Bid%2C%20data%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20previousContainer%2C%20previousContainer%3A%20%7Bdata%3A%20prevData%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20currentIndex%0A%20%20%7D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasRole%20%3D%20pluck%28%27role%27%2C%20data%29.includes%28prevData%5BpreviousIndex%5D.role%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21hasRole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lastAddedRole%20%3D%20data%5BpreviousIndex%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28lastAddedRole%20%21%3D%3D%20undefined%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28%7B...lastAddedRole%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A), like this:

```js
        let hasRole = pluck('role', data).includes(prevData[previousIndex].role)
```

And now that we can extract helpers, we can do a substantial clean-up of our main function by adding a few helper methods to our object:

```js
  deleteRole: function (prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex) {
    transferArrayItem(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
    this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
  },
  transferRole: function(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex) {
    if (!pluck('role', data).includes(prevData[previousIndex].role)) {
      transferArrayItem(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
      if (previousIndex in data) {
        this.userRoleCopy.push({...data[previousIndex]});
      }
      this.resetList();
    }
  },
  drop: function ({
    container, container: {id, data},
    previousContainer, previousContainer: {data: prevData},
    previousIndex,
    currentIndex
  }) {
    if (id === "delete") {
      this.deleteRole(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
    } else {
      if (previousContainer === container) {
        moveItemInArray(data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
      } else {
        this.transferRole(prevData, data, previousIndex, currentIndex);
      }
    }
  }
```

(This is [Step 5](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20deleteRole%3A%20function%20%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20transferRole%3A%20function%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21pluck%28%27role%27%2C%20data%29.includes%28prevData%5BpreviousIndex%5D.role%29%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferArrayItem%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28previousIndex%20in%20data%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28%7B...data%5BpreviousIndex%5D%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20container%2C%20container%3A%20%7Bid%2C%20data%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20previousContainer%2C%20previousContainer%3A%20%7Bdata%3A%20prevData%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20previousIndex%2C%0A%20%20%20%20currentIndex%0A%20%20%7D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.deleteRole%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveItemInArray%28data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.transferRole%28prevData%2C%20data%2C%20previousIndex%2C%20currentIndex%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A%0A).)

### Moving back to an `event` parameter

As we've proceeded, it seems as though the decision to destructure our `event` parameter is actually complicating things.  Certainly the signature of our main function is not as nice as we'd like.  If we undo that, now that we've abstracted things a bit, using these property accesses doesn't seem so ugly.

And this would let us move some of the helpers from object methods to plain functions, which are often more tractable.  There is a problem with the `this` property though, which would necessitate moving this line back into the main function:

```js
   this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
```

With this the code now could look like [Step 6](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20transferEvent%20%3D%20%28event%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20transferArrayItem%28event.previousContainer.data%2C%20event.container.data%2C%20event.previousIndex%2C%20event.currentIndex%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20moveEvent%20%3D%20%28event%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20moveItemInArray%28event.container.data%2C%20event.previousIndex%2C%20event.currentIndex%29%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%0A%20%20transferRole%3A%20function%28event%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21pluck%28%27role%27%2C%20event.container.data%29.includes%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D.role%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousIndex%20in%20event.container.data%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy.push%28%7B...event.container.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%20%28event%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.container.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20event.container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.transferRole%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A%0A):

```js
const pluck = (prop) => (xs) => xs.map(x => x[prop])

const transferEvent = (event) =>
  transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

const moveEvent = (event) => 
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex)

const something = (userRole) => ({
  // ...
  transferRole: function(event) {
    if (!pluck('role', event.container.data).includes(
      event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].role)
     ) {
      transferEvent(event);
      if (event.previousIndex in event.container.data) {
        this.userRoleCopy.push({...event.container.data[event.previousIndex]});
      }
      this.resetList();
    }
  },
  drop: function (event) {
    if (event.container.id === "delete") {
      transferEvent(event);
      this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
    } else {
      if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        moveEvent(event);
      } else {
        this.transferRole(event);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

### Making plain functions out of methods

The reason we haven't been able to move `transferRole` into a plain function as well is that it makes reference to `this`.  So long as we need `this`, we're stuck with methods.  But it's quite easy to make it a function parameter.  When we do so we end up with a final cleaner codebase, [Step 7](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20transferArrayItem%20%3D%20%28prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27transfer%27%2C%20prevData%2C%20currData%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%20%0A%0Aconst%20moveItemInArray%20%3D%20%28data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27move%27%2C%20data%2C%20prevIdx%2C%20currIdx%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20transferEvent%20%3D%20%28event%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20transferArrayItem%28event.previousContainer.data%2C%20event.container.data%2C%20event.previousIndex%2C%20event.currentIndex%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20moveEvent%20%3D%20%28event%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20moveItemInArray%28event.container.data%2C%20event.previousIndex%2C%20event.currentIndex%29%0A%0Aconst%20transferRole%20%3D%20%28something%2C%20event%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20%28%21pluck%28%27role%27%2C%20event.container.data%29.includes%28%0A%20%20%20%20event.previousContainer.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D.role%29%0A%20%20%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20transferEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousIndex%20in%20event.container.data%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20something.userRoleCopy.push%28%7B...event.container.data%5Bevent.previousIndex%5D%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20something.resetList%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20%28userRole%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20userRole%2C%0A%20%20userRoleCopy%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20resetList%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%7Baction%3A%20%27resetList%27%7D%29%2C%0A%0A%20%20drop%3A%20function%20%28event%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.container.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22delete%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transferEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.userRoleCopy%20%3D%20this.userRole.slice%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28event.previousContainer%20%3D%3D%3D%20event.container%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveEvent%28event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transferRole%28this%2C%20event%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0Aconst%20containers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27b1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27b5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27a1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a2%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a3%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a4%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27a5%27%7D%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%27delete%27%2C%20data%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20s%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%2F%2F------------------------------------%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.d%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.b%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%27%29%0As%20%3D%20something%20%28%5B%7Brole%3A%20%27x1%27%7D%2C%20%7Brole%3A%20%27x2%27%7D%5D%29%0As%20.drop%20%28%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20containers.a%2C%0A%20%20previousContainer%3A%20containers.c%2C%0A%20%20previousIndex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20currentIndex%3A%203%0A%7D%29%0Aconsole.log%28s%29%0A%0A%0A):

```js
const pluck = (prop) => (xs) => xs.map(x => x[prop])

const transferEvent = (event) =>
  transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

const moveEvent = (event) => 
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex)

const transferRole = (something, event) => {
  if (!pluck('role', event.container.data).includes(
    event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex].role)
  ) {
    transferEvent(event);
    if (event.previousIndex in event.container.data) {
      something.userRoleCopy.push({...event.container.data[event.previousIndex]});
    }
    something.resetList();
  }
};

const something = (userRole) => ({tion: 'resetList'}),
  // ...
  drop: function (event) {
    if (event.container.id === "delete") {
      transferEvent(event);
      this.userRoleCopy = this.userRole.slice();
    } else {
      if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        moveEvent(event);
      } else {
        transferRole(this, event);
      }
    }
  },
})
```

### Lessons Learned

I was going to write a few paragraphs about choices made during this refactoring, and about alternatives that might apply.  But I'm tired now, and want to finish up.  So I'll just say although there are many good reasons to refactor code -- including performance, compliance with conventions and standards, and others -- the most important reason is to make your code easier to read and to modify.

I believe the final version makes the branching much more clear.  I believe it is easier to read.  So I believe we have improved this code.

---

Note: I'm seeing after writing all this up that we folded two separate changes into Step 5.  As well as pulling out helper functions, that step changed this:

```js
          let lastAddedRole = data[previousIndex];
          if (lastAddedRole !== undefined) {
            this.userRoleCopy.push({...lastAddedRole});
          }
```

to this:

```js
      if (previousIndex in data) {
        this.userRoleCopy.push({...data[previousIndex]});
      }
```

It does the same thing, but without introducing a temporary variable.  To me that's usually an improvement.

Comment: Than you soo much... It's helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

My first question seeing your code is if all conditions are mutually exclusive. In other words, do you want the code inside the `else` block to be used if the `if` condition is not met? Or it would be fine to go to the `else` code regardless if the first condition was met.

I also recommend following these guidelines to avoid this kind of code [flattening arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Answer (score 1):

There are some parts you could split out that only need `event` as a parameter.

```
transferArrayItem(
  event.previousContainer.data,
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex
);
```

could be wrapped in something that takes the dragdrop event as a parameter.

I don't quite understand what you're doing in `checkIfHasRole()` - it seems as if you've put everything (except `this.resetList()`) within `if (!hasRole)` into a function named as if it performed the `hasRole` checks in the previous lines?

You could turn `hasRole` into a function containing

```
  let lastRole = Object.values(
    event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]
  );
  let parentRole = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.container.data));

  return parentRole.some(rola => rola.role === String(lastRole));
```

The way `lastRole` is accessed seems confusing. Can you log `event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]` to see why on earth that's accessed through `String(Object.values())`?